# fetching mac address on MI or Xiaomi phones android

Tags: android, xiaomi

I am fetching the mobile's mac address with the following code and its working perfectly fine on android devices.The code for getting mac address I got from stackoverflow. But on MI or Xiaomi phones fetching mac address isnt working.. Please guide. Below is my code. The user gets access to the app by entering his mobile number and mac address will be sent in the url

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 public void onClick(View view) {
            ConnectivityManager ConnectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = ConnectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() == true) {
                //get data from screen
                getMacAddr();
                mobile = mobile_no.getText().toString();
                String url = "https://sugarapp.web4rest.com/verify_user.php?mobile="+mobile+"&mac="+mac_addr;
                    if(mobile.isEmpty() || !mobile.matches(MOBILE_PATTERN)) {
                    builder.setTitle("Something went wrong!!");
                    displayAlert("You have not entered Mobile Number");
                }else {
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response);
                                        if (Integer.parseInt(jobject.getString("status")) == 200) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            mobile_no.setText("");
                                            port_no.setText("");
                                            session.setLoggedin(true);
                                            getData(); //Shared p call
                                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        Log.e("Error", "Login Failed" + e.toString());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> parmams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            parmams.put("mobile_no", mobile);
                            parmams.put("mac", mac_addr);
                            return parmams;
                        }
                    };
                    MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
                }

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
public String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            mac_addr = res1.toString();
            return mac_addr;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you made `getMacAddr()` return String, disregard it, then use a variable `mac_addr`, out of the air? Wouldnt `String mac_addr = getMacAddr();` make more sense? The code shown will never compile.

Comment: Note that according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#version_specific_details_identifiers_in_m), MAC addresses for the local device can no longer be accessed via third party APIs after Android 6.0. Were your other android devices all of a lower API level?

Comment: @ TheGamer007 - nope. I have tested on API 26 & 27..nougat as well